# How to fix The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I want to update all info of one tabla with info of other table in different database servers.

I'm trying with this but give me error.

```
update remotolocal.pruebasjon.dbo.albaranesJon  
set remotolocal.pruebasjon.dbo.albaranesJon = albaranesJon
```

The multi-part identifier `remotolocal.pruebasjon.dbo.albaranesJon` could not be bound.

Comment: Why is this tagged ASP.NET and not SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition for `UPDATE` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it states that only column names can be specified in the `SET` clause. I am not aware of any option that allows you to use `UPDATE` to copy a table.

Also, the target and source are the same.

There are a variety of tools to do this, for example, `bcp` utility. This is referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017)